# sitecore permissions for aliases folder

Tags: security, permissions, sitecore, sitecore6

I've create a role and added to it read, write and create permissions inside the folder `/Sitecore/System/Aliases` for users that need to create or edit aliases to web pages. However, when editing those permissions, the security editor shows the System folder grayed out and i can't set it to read. When i log as an user with this role, i cannot navigate to the alias folder

What permissions/role do i need to add to this role in order that it can access the Aliases folder?

I'm working with sitecore 6.5.0

Answer (score 1):

The System item is Protected by default, so you'll need to log in as the root admin and Un-protect it before making those changes. Once you make the changes though, I recommend you protect it again.

Comment: thanks. what you mean 'root admin'? can any admin user do it?

Comment: any user with `IsAdministrator` check box turned ON in the user profile is able to do this

Comment: Yes, as Yan said, any admin user can do it.

Answer (score 1):

The System Folder should remain protected and only accessible to Admins and Developers IMHO.  For controlling access to creating Aliases, you should control the Alias menu item in the presentation ribbon instead.  To do this, deny access to the following chunk in the CORE DB for the given Role...

/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Page Urls